# TextBox.Text accept decimal inputs only

Tags: vb.net

How to make `txtamount.text` accept only decimal values,it should accept only one `.` not more than one.

My following is my try but it accept more `.`

```
Private Sub txtamount_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtamount.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 46 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use `NumericUpDown` instead of `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
        Dim asccode As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)
        If asccode <> 8 Then
            If asccode = 46 And txtPackageAmount.Text.Contains(".") Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
            If (asccode < 48 Or asccode > 57) And asccode <> 46 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) instead.  That has a property called DecimalPlaces where you can set the limit of how many decimals the user can enter.  Then you would not need any code just to validate only 1 "." is entered.